# Asp.NET drop down list adding list items from list in a form of a tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a method in which I have to populate dropdownlist from a collection that is formed like a tree. I have list of parent Objects, every parent can have list of child Objects, every child can have list of grandchild Objects and so on.
I have to loop through tha collection because I want to indent items so hierarchy is built.

ddl should look like this:(- is symbol for indent)
parent
 -child
  --grandchild
   ---grandgrandchild
 -child
parent
..and so on..

How should I go about changing this method so i dont have loop inside a loop inside a loop, asume I dont know the depht of a tree

Thanks in advance!

Method:

```
private void BindObjectDropDown()
    {
        ddlObject.Items.Clear();

        ObjectCollection collection = Object.GetList();

        if (collection != null && collection.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var parent in collection)
            {
                ddlObject.Items.Add(new ListItem($"{parent.Title}", parent.Id.ToString()));
                if (parent.Objects != null && parent.Objects.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var child in parent.Objects)
                    {
                        ddlObject.Items.Add(new ListItem($"{_ddlIndent}{child.Title}", child.Id.ToString()));

                        if (child.Objects != null && child.Objects.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var grandchild in child.Objects)
                            {
                                ddlObject.Items.Add(new ListItem($"{_ddlIndent}{_ddlIndent}{grandchild.Title}", grandchild.Id.ToString()));

                                //and so on and so on ....

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (ListItem item in ddlObject.Items)
            {
                item.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone wants a solution, recursion, of course:

```
private void BindMyObjectDropDown()
    {
        ddlMyObject.Items.Clear();

        MyObjectCollection collection = MyObject.GetList(0, true);

        if (collection != null && collection.Count > 0)
        {
            AddDdlItems(collection, 0);

            foreach (ListItem item in ddlMyObject.Items)
            {
                item.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Text);
            }
        }
        ddlMyObject.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(EntityResource.DefaultDropDownPick, "0"));
    }

    private void AddDdlItems(MyObjectCollection collection, int depth)
    {
        string indent = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        {
            indent += _ddlIndent;
        }

        foreach (var myObject in collection)
        {
            ddlMyObject.Items.Add(new ListItem($"{indent}{myObject.Title}", myObject.Id.ToString()));

            if (myObject.Objects!= null && myObject.Objects.Count > 0)
            {
                AddDdlItems(myObject.Objects, depth + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```